# Property without @synthesis is not iniatialized for custom objects

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am working on an app in which I have created some classes for model, view and for controllers.

There are few model classes namely

**CellModel.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CellModel : NSObject{

}
@property(nonatomic, assign)BOOL isSelected;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *headingText;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *subHeadingText;

@end
```

**CellModel.m**

```
#import "CellModel.h"

@implementation CellModel

@end
```

Classes mentioned above will act as model object for each cell

**TableModel.h**

```
/*This is the model class navgation bar menu and will contain objects of "CellModel only"*/
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TableModel : NSObject{

}
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray* menuOptionsArray;

@end
```

and

**TableModel.m**

```
#import "TableModel.h"

@implementation TableModel

@end
```

now in the view controller class i have created property of type TableModel named as *tableModelObj. and in a method I am adding different object of type CellModel in tableModelObj.menuOptionArray

but I don't know why but when I try to add objects in this array the object "tableModelObj" is always empty.

P.S. I dont want to synthesize my properties because in XCode 4.6 it is not necessary to do so.

Comment: Are you using custom setter and getter for that property?

Comment: No, I am not defining any custom setter getter for any of these properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think is not the table model that is empty, is that probably you need to initialise the mutable (menuOptionsArray) array before adding elements...

Comment: but it is a property, and If I am not wrong then properties are already initialized if we haven't defined custom getter and setters for them

Comment: No.. You need to create the associated object. Property is just a way to access the instance variable.

Comment: @VaibhavGautam Default initialisation will involve creating an ivar and setting it as `nil`. But you need to create the container i.e. array, so you need to override the default `init` of your class `TableModel` and allocate the array.

Answer (score 2):

`@synthesize` will create the property getter/setter methods, but it won't allocate the object's instance variables and it won't release them.  You need:

```
@implementation TableModel

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // NOTE! an autorelease object is used
        self.menuOptionsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    self.menuOptionsArray = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

You need to do this for all your objects when using MRR.

Answer (score 0):

The getter and the setter are indeed generated for you, but all they do is to either set or return the value you stored in the iVar, no initialization is performed at any point.

The best practice is to create a custom lazy initializer getter. For example, the most basic option is to do:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)menuOptionsArray
{
   if(!_menuOptionsArray)
      _menuOptionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   return _menuOptionsArray;
}
```